# Need to show message after purchase receipt is released

Tags: acumatica

I need to show some message to the user after Purchase Receipt is released, so I added my code in Released Field updated event and I tried PXOperationCompletedException method to show some message, but the problem is, Purchase Receipts is released and Inventory Receipts is also created but not released. Can someone please suggest me how to show a custom message (like a popup) after Purchase Receipt is released.

```
public class INReleaseProcessExt : PXGraphExtension<INReleaseProcess>
{
  protected void INRegister_Released_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e, PXFieldUpdated BaseEvent)
  {
    BaseEvent?.Invoke(cache, e);

    INRegister row = e.Row as INRegister;

    if (row == null)
        return;

    if (row.OrigModule == "PO")
        throw new PXOperationCompletedException("Purchse Receipt is released");
   }
}
```

Comment: I assume you want to view something more than the process results showing process completed? Are you looking to show some type of inventory receipt number? What happens if the user is processing multiple PO receipts? will your message stop the process after the first?

Comment: Thanks for reply Brendan, actually, I have a button on Purchase Receipts screen which will be enabled only after PR is released, this button will create some other document with PR data and it is mandatory to click on the button, but sometimes users are forgetting to click on it. So I want to remind them to click on the button. It is not required to show any reference numbers, i just want to show a message like, "please click on the button before proceeding any further".

Comment: what if you just process the additional step if its always required? You should be able to override POReceiptEntry ReleaseReceipt to do this

Comment: Actually, yes I thought of processing new button action in PR release action only but the button in PR is created by some other partner.

Comment: sound like if it is required to always run to create another project and wire up that process to auto run from ReleaseReceipt. Seems like a more solid solution to me. Users are not the best at actually readying the pop up box :)  The pop up box might get a little tricky and could prevent the receipt process from executing correctly (as you have already discovered in one way)

Comment: Thanks for input Brendan, will give a try and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

Throwing an exception will abort the current operation as well as display a message.

To display a message without aborting the current operation use the [Ask](https://asiablog.acumatica.com/2015/11/using-smart-panel.html) method.